# Who appointed the term Multiton originally?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, multiton

Who appointed the term Multiton originally? I am referring to a variation of the singleton pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern

Why the word “Multiton”? That’s not a real English word. Isn’t it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a generalization of the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which just allows one instance of a class. Singleton by the way is also a mathematical term.
As far as I know, it's not a proper english word and we don't know the first person who used this term.

Comment: Are you saying that: Singleton = Single + Ton, and thus, Multiton = Multi + Ton???

Comment: In mathematics a singleton set is a set with just one value, for example X = { 5 }. Therefore yes, although the mathematical term multiton does not exist.

Comment: I know understand the origin of the word Multiton, but who baptized the pattern with that name anyway? Is there any book, author that I can take as a reference?